# How to hide our own application

Tags: cocoa

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] hideOtherApplications];// Insert code here to initialize your application

}
```

That would hideOtherApplications. What should we do to also hide our own main windows?

Comment: what are you trying to do?  do you want to hide your application after it launches?  why not just launch your app as a "background only" app, or minimize the window that your app opens?

Comment: How to launch app as background only app? How to  minimize the windows my app opens?

Comment: @JimThio: For the former, see the Info Property List Key Reference. (You have two choices: UI Element or Background-Only. There's a difference.) For the latter, send each of them a `miniaturize:` or `performMiniaturize:` message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Mac OS X 10.6 and later:

```
[[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] hide];
```

Comment: Is this equivalent with user pressing the red button?

Comment: @JimThio: The red button on a window closes that window; it has nothing to do with the application.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
NSRunningApplication.current.hide()
```